# How to apply IPageFilter to only OnPost handler in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to apply `IPageFilter` to just `OnPost` handler in razor pages.
like this:

```
[MyFilter] 
public IActionResult OnPost() {  // any code }
```

But when I do this the Visual studio force me to apply my filter to above of class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only apply the `IPageFilter` attribute to a `PageModel` and not its individual page handler methods, a suitable solution would be to validate the calling a handler method in the `OnPageHandlerSelected` method of your filter implementation.

A sample code implementation would be:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public class CustomPageFilter : IPageFilter
{
    public void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HandlerMethod.IsDefaultPost())
        {
            // Code to execute when the page handler method is selected
            Log("Page handler method selected");
        }
    }

    public void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HandlerMethod.IsDefaultPost())
        {
            // Code to execute before the page handler method
            Log("Executing before the page handler method");
        }
    }

    public void OnPageHandlerExecuted(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HandlerMethod.IsDefaultPost())
        {
            // Code to execute after the page handler method
            Log("Executed after the page handler method");
        }
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        // Your logging logic here
    }
}
```

The `IsDefaultPost` is an extension method that validates whether the calling handler is the primary/default POST handler method. In this method, we validate that the handler method Name is `null` and the HttpMethod is `POST`.

The code for the extension is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure;

public static class HandlerMethodDescriptorExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefaultGet(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) && handlerMethod.HttpMethod.ToLower() == HttpMethods.Get.ToLower();
    }
    public static bool IsDefaultPost(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) && handlerMethod.HttpMethod.ToLower() == HttpMethods.Post.ToLower();
    }
    public static bool IsMethodName(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod, string handlerMethodName)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) && handlerMethod.Name == handlerMethodName;
    }
    public static bool IsMethodName(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod, string handlerMethodName, string httpMethod)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) && handlerMethod.Name == handlerMethodName && handlerMethod.HttpMethod.ToLower() == httpMethod.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can use the `IsDefaultGet()` to validate whether the calling handler method is the primary `GET` method. You can also use the `IsMethodName(,)` to determine whether the calling handler method matches the name you specify.

For example:

```
bool isMyMethod = context.HandlerMethod.IsMethodName("MyMethod");
```

Or, if you wish to include the HttpMethod parameter:

```
bool isMyMethod = context.HandlerMethod.IsMethodName("MyMethod", HttpMethods.Post);
```

Comment: It would be nice to include and validate with `context.HandlerMethod.MethodInfo.Name` rather than `context.HandlerMethod.Name`. This way you can perform strongly typed validations and checks.

Comment: Such that instead of using the string `"MyMethod"` you can simply pass `nameof(OnGetMyMethodAsync)` in your extension parameter

Answer (score 0):

From [Filter methods for Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-7.0) we can see

> Razor Page filters IPageFilter and IAsyncPageFilter allow Razor Pages
> to run code before and after a Razor Page handler is run. Razor Page
> filters are similar to ASP.NET Core MVC action filters, except they
> can't be applied to individual page handler methods.

If you definitely wants to add a filter to the handler, you can submit a new feature request on GitHub.